# how to get result of 'select count(*) from myapp_table' in Django's RawQuerySet

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get number of record with RawQuerySet in db table.

I don't know how to access value of count(*).

belows are my tries,

```
>>> q = Question.objects.raw('select count(*) from poll_Question')

>>> q[0]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1323, in __getitem__
    return list(self)[k]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1296, in __iter__
    raise InvalidQuery('Raw query must include the primary key')
django.db.models.query_utils.InvalidQuery: Raw query must include the primary key
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Django docs.

> This method takes a raw SQL query, executes it, and returns a
>   django.db.models.query.RawQuerySet instance. This RawQuerySet instance
>   can be iterated over just like a normal QuerySet to provide object
>   instances.

You can use cursor instead.

```
cursor.execute('count query')
```

Or you can do this way, Beware this method is very ineffective, what it does, it loads all poll_question in memory and then performs count operation. You must perform count operation in Database, Database are meant to perform operation like count and sum.

```
q = Question.objects.raw('select * from poll_Question')
print len(list(q))
```

Comment: 1/2 your answer is very good... the other 1/2 is very very inefficient way to count a record set.

Answer (score 1):

U can try to include id in your SQL it works fine

```
Question.objects.raw('select 1 as id , count(*) as total_polls from poll_Question')
```

Answer (score 0):

'select count(id) from poll_Question' would likely solve your issue (assuming id is the primary key).

However, why not just use Djangos ORM and call PollQuestion.objects.count()?

Comment: Of course I know it can be solved with ORM. But I want to know how can I resolve in manner of manager API and I don't know how can I get the value of SQL function result.

Comment: you can use cursor.execute to execute any mysql query, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need can be achieved with:

```
Question.objects.count()
```